# Como posso escrever num arquivo do servidor usando FS do Node?

Tags: node.js, fs

Está rodando na minha máquina servidor o comando:

```
$ http-server . -p 3333
```

Tudo perfeito quando acesso desde um navegador Web de outra máquina (também Linux).

Porém ao rodar este script em Node, não consigo escrever num arquivo que está no servidor, nem me retorna erro. Por que o **fs writeFile** não funciona com um endereço IP? Há alguma solução para isso?

```js
app.post('/formulario', (req, res) => {
 nome = req.body.nome
 idade = req.body.idade
 console.log('Nome.:', nome, '\nIdade:', Number(idade)+10)
 res.send('Nome.: '  + nome + '<br>Idade: ' + idade)
 fs.writeFile('http://192.168.0.113:3333/arquivoTeste.txt', 'Nome.: '+ nome, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Escrito!');
 })
 res.end()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

Para você acessar algo você deve passar o **path** de onde o mesmo se encontra, no seu caso você tenta acessar um ip e uma porta mas isso não te leva a diretorio nenhum dentro da maquina, por exemplo, um ftp lhe da acesso direto a uma pasta dentro da maquina atravez do ip + porta (exemplo: 192.168.0.5:21), uma outra coisa porque você não utiliza um banco de dados para poder  armazenar suas informações em vez de um arquivo?

Comment: Obrigado Gustavo. Eu consegui acessar de outra máquina o app pela porta, etx e percebi que salvava e acessava os dados perfeitamente. Supriu a necessidade. Foi algo simples por isso nao optei por um banco de dados.